# WooCommerce prevent checkout until post code entered

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, postal-code

Trying to prevent customers from the "Proceed to payment" button until the postcode has been entered. However, I found that with the function below that if you change quantity and update cart - the function no longer works and you can proceed with the payment free of shipping. Any ideas?

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'prevent_proceed_to_checkout' );

function prevent_proceed_to_checkout() {
    echo 'alert(Please enter postcode before payment!")';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated - 3 ways - (Added an alternative)

1) You can use the following code that will "avoid proceed to checkout" checkout if a postcode has not been filled:

```
// Avoiding checkout when postcode has not been entered
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'check_shipping_postcode' ); // Cart and Checkout
function check_shipping_postcode() {
    $customer = WC()->session->get('customer');
    if( ! $customer['calculated_shipping'] || empty( $customer['shipping_postcode'] ) ){
        // Display an error message
        wc_add_notice( __("Please enter your postcode before checkout", "woocommerce"), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**In Cart page:**

[image]

**In checkout page:**

[image]

---

2) Try this alternative way (that check for postcode and redirect to cart avoiding checkout):

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'check_shipping_postcode');
function check_shipping_postcode() {
    // Only on checkout page (and cart for the displayed message)
    if ( ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) || is_cart() ) {
        $customer = WC()->session->get('customer');
        if( ! $customer['calculated_shipping'] || empty( $customer['shipping_postcode'] ) ){
            wc_add_notice( __("Please enter your postcode before checkout", "woocommerce"), 'error' );
            if( ! is_cart() ){
                wp_redirect(wc_get_cart_url());
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**In Cart page:**

[image]

---

3) A combination of both above (avoiding checkout page):

```
// Avoiding checkout when postcode has not been entered
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'check_shipping_postcode' ); // Cart and Checkout
function check_shipping_postcode() {
    $customer = WC()->session->get('customer');
    if( ! $customer['calculated_shipping'] || empty( $customer['shipping_postcode'] ) ){
        // Display an error message
        wc_add_notice( __("Please enter your postcode before checkout", "woocommerce"), 'error' );
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'shipping_postcode_redirection');
function shipping_postcode_redirection() {
    // Only on checkout page
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        $customer = WC()->session->get('customer');
        if( ! $customer['calculated_shipping'] || empty( $customer['shipping_postcode'] ) ){
            wp_redirect(wc_get_cart_url());
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**In Cart page:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but didnt work unfortunately, maybe because i have a third party payment gateway? Nothing really happend other than the notice showed up immediately when in cart

Comment: @ViktorFonster Strange… I have added a 2nd alternative… please try it. It should work even if you have a custom payment gateway.

Comment: Cool! It pretty much worked! Even if you change quanitity etc. Only problem is that the cart simple reloads and the error notice isnt showing. Maybe a lazy solution would be if I redirected users to a page with the notice and a back to cart button (which wouldn't be that great), or to simply have a big notice which always is showing saying the postcode is required?

Comment: didnt make a difference, unfortunetly :(

Comment: Yes indeed, especially because the notice did show on the first snippet :/

Comment: Using the second one which works excep the notice. But the first one the notice worked but didnt stop me from getting past to payment without postcode.

Comment: @ViktorFonster I have maid a 3rd alternative that should fit your needs then.

Comment: Working! Thank you so much for helping, very appriciated!

Comment: I am using this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/check-pincodezipcode-for-shipping-woocommerce/
how can I make the pincode field complusory before adding to cart ? how can i find hooks related to it ?